# Laravel Mutator in query builder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've no idea how to define two field as one field using mutator in query builder 
here's my code

```
$model = LoanInformation::select( 
    'basic_information.first_name', 'basic_information.last_name',
    'loan_information.id', 'loan_information.tenor'
)->join(
    'basic_information', 'loan_information.user_id', '=', 'basic_information.user_id'
)->where(
    'loan_information.status', 'funding'
)->paginate(9);
```

How can I make first_name and last_name define as name and add statement on it which return `strtoupper(first_name)` and `strtoupper(last_name)`

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your `LoanInformation` model, add the following method:

```
public function getNameAttribute() {
    return strtoupper($this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name);
}
```

This will enable you to write `$model->name` which will return the firstname and lastname, joined with a space, all in uppercase.

Comment: and if I want it especially in that builder?

Answer (score 0):

I just figure it out by adding key and value to the array instead of mutator or accessor

here's my own answer

```
$model = LoanInformation::select(
       'loan_information.id', 'loan_information.tenor',
       'basic_information.first_name', 'basic_information.last_name'
)->leftjoin(
       'basic_information', 'loan_information.user_id', '=', 
       'basic_information.user_id'
)->where('loan_information.status', 'funding')
->orderBy('loan_information.created_at', 'ASC')
->paginate(9);

foreach($model as $key => $value) {
   $tx_funding = TxFunding::whereLoanId($value->id)->get();
   $name = substr($value->first_name, 0, 1).substr($value->last_name, 0, 2);

   $model[$key]['name'] = strtoupper($name);
   $model[$key]['grade'] = 'A+';
   $model[$key]['fundraiser'] = $tx_funding->count();
   $model[$key]['progress'] = 50;
   $model[$key] = array_except($value, ['first_name', 'last_name']);
}

return response()->json($model);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add two step in relvant modal:
1.`protected $appends = ['name'];`
2.`public function getNameAttribute() { return strtoupper($this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name); }`

now you get name value through $modelname->name;